# Implementing a determinate CircularProgressIndicator in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I understand how to implement an **indeterminate** progress indicator, but how would you implement a **determinate** indicator tied to an animation over a specific duration?

Example code:

```
double _barValue = 1.0;

_animation = Tween(
    begin: 1.0,
    end: 0.0,
).animate(animationController)
    ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
            _barValue = _animation.value;
        });
    });

CircularProgressIndicator(
    value: _barValue,
    // colorValue: <-- how do you implement this??
    backgroundColor: tangerine.withAlpha(100),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to change colour as the bar progresses, use something like the below. This example will fade from blue at 0% to red at 100% using the same value as the progress in your example:

```
class _MyClassState extends State<_MyClass> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
    AnimationController _colorAnimationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    ...
    _colorAnimationController = AnimationController(vsync: this);
    ...
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    ...
    _colorAnimationController?.dispose();
    ...
  }

  // In your build method:
    Animation<Color> _colorAnimation = ColorTween(
        begin: Colors.blue,
        end: Colors.red,
    ).animate(
      _colorAnimationController
    );


    // Use inside setState, for example
    _colorAnimationController.value = _barValue;

    ...

    CircularProgressIndicator(
      value: _barValue,
      valueColor: _colorAnimation,
    ),
}
```

If you want it to change colours in some kind of pattern separate to the progress, just set the AnimationController up and run it as you would with any other animation.

If you just want to override the value to a specific colour:

```
    CircularProgressIndicator(
      value: val,
      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
    ),
```